# CSS position transitions and display:none

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a content where I have items tagged within different categories. All are displayed as block div's; all are identical.

There is an option to hide/unhide certain categories of items. Hidden items are marked as `display:none` and the rest stays the same.

Normally, as you can imagine, rest of the items instantly fill-up the space left from the hidden items. However, I want this to happen with a CSS position transition so things don't happen instantly but happen over time instead.

Just to make things easier for testing, I've added this bit to my CSS file:

```
*{
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Here is a codepen link:

http://codepen.io/zettam/pen/bazqF

When the "hidden" class is added to the item, the item is disappearing instantly therefore no transition is happening. Any ideas on how to make this transition/repositioning possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/03/15/animating-lists-with-css-3-transitions/

Comment: That's very close! Is it possible to achieve similar results without using translate3d?

Comment: You can use translate and the values from to with a pixel position. Find and example: http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/moving-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-translate-transform/

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are asking for BUT I believe this may help

```
transition : position 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition : position 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition : position 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition : position 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: I want the remaining elements to position themselves using transition.